# How to run two process independently with their own thread pool and other configuration?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

I have two `processes` as shown below in the List.

```
public static final ImmutableList<String> processes = ImmutableList.of("processA", "processB");
```

Now for each `process`, I have a different `Properties` object and there is no relation and dependency between those two process at all. They are independent of each other.

I wrote a code that works with only one process for now and I need to extend my design efficiently so that it can work for two process. Each process should have it's own Thread Pool configuration. For example, may be I want to run `processA` with three threads and `processB` with two threads.

```
public class ProcessA implements Runnable {
  private final Properties props;
  private final String processName;

  public ProcessA(String processName, Properties props) {
    this.processName = processName;
    this.props = props;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    List<String> clients = getClients(processName);
    try {
      // .. some code here which does  processing
      // calling some classes here as well

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // log error
    } finally {
      // close processA here
    }
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    // shutdown processA here
  }
}
```

Below is my main class where I execute my `processA`. In general I will be executing my both the processes from below class only.

```
@Singleton
@DependencyInjectionInitializer
public class Initializer {
  private final ExecutorService executorServiceProcessA = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
  private final List<ProcessA> processAList = new ArrayList<>();

  public Initializer() {
    logger.logInfo("initializing here called.");
    TestUtils.getInstance().initializeData();
  }  

  // this is the entrance point for my code
  @PostConstruct
  public void postInit() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ProcessA process =
            new ProcessA("processA", properties);
        processAList.add(process);
        executorServiceProcessA.submit(process);         
    }       
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        for (ProcessA process : processAList) {
          process.shutdown();
        }
        executorServiceProcessA.shutdown();
        try {
          executorServiceProcessA.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I will have only one `Initializer` class which will execute both my process from its `postInit` method and then shutdown both the  process from its `shutdown` method.

**Problem Statement:-**

Now how can I extend my design so that it can work with two `processes` efficiently? Each process should have its own thread pool, its own properties object and I should be able to execute them from `postInit` method and then shutdown later from `shutdown` method.

What is the best and efficient way to do that?

Comment: Are you using JDK 7 or 8 ?

Comment: @david do you use spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clear **violation of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle** in your code.

In other words, **there is lots of Boilerplate code** in your `Process` and `Main` classes which can be eliminated by using the abstract classes (or use interfaces if you use Java8 with `default` methods).

So I have created two `Process` and `ProcessHandler` abstract classes to reuse the code which is common across each process and process handling.
So now, you can define `ProcessA`, `ProcessB` classes which extend Process and `ProcessHandlerA`, `ProcesshandlerB` which extend ProcessHandler class.

The key point is **this solution can be extended to any number of `Process` **, i.e., this follows **Open/Closed principle of OOP**.

*You can refer the below code with comments:*

**Process class (abstract):**

```
public abstract Process implements Runnable {

        private final Properties props;
        private final String processName;

        public Process(String processName, Properties props) {
            this.processName = processName;
            this.props = props;
        }

        //this can also be a non abstract (reusable) method 
        // to eliminate boiler plate code (if any)
        public abstract void shutdown();
    }
```

**ProcessA class:**

```
public class ProcessA extends Process {

          public ProcessA(String processName, Properties props) {
              super(processName, props);
          }

          @Override
          public void run() {
              //add run code here
          }

          @Override
          public void shutdown() {
              //shut down code
          }
    }
```

**Process B class:**

//Similar to `ProcessA` with specific details of B

**ProcessHandler class (abstract):**

```
public abstract class ProcessHandler {

         private final ExecutorService executorServiceProcess;
         private final List<Process> processList;
         private int poolSize;

         protected ProcessHandler(int poolSize) {
             executorServiceProcess = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
             processList = new ArrayList<>();
             this.poolSize = poolSize;
         }

          public void postInit(Process process) {
             for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++) {
                    processList.add(process);
                    executorServiceProcess.submit(process);    
              }  
          }

         public void shutdown() {
                Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (Process process : processList) {
                      process.shutdown();
                    }
                    executorServiceProcess.shutdown();
                    try {
                      executorServiceProcess.
                        awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                  }
                });
         }
 }
```

**ProcessHandlerA class:**

```
public class ProcessHandlerA extends ProcessHandler {

          public ProcessHandlerA() {
              super(3);//configure pool size properly w.r.to ProcessA requirements
          }

          public void postInit() {
              ProcessA processA = new ProcessA("processA", properties);
              super(processA);
          }

          public void shutdown() {
              super.shutdown();
          }
     }
```

**ProcessHandlerB class:**

//Similar to ProcessHandlerA with specific details for B